# Get list of connected microphone devices in Xamarin.forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to get the list of connected audio device in Xamarin android? My app is basically to record the conversation, meetings etc. I would want to get list of audio recording devices available in Android.

I suppose we can connect a usb microphone to a android device(not sure though). So in that case what will happen? When Android device will try to record a sound which audio device will it take? Or is it by default that only one audio device can be plugged in anytime?

I want user to select the device from which he would like to record sound on Android. So would I have to put a drop-down for user to select the audio device or would it be only 1 option all the time? If multiple options then how do I get list of available device?